# If an object x is an instance of a type T, then what is a type T for a concept C?

Tags: c++, terminology, concepts, instance

In concept-based programming (as in `C++` concepts), I am wondering if there is a noun to say that:

> A type `T` is an `XXXX` of a concept `C`.

in the same way we can say that:

> An object `x` is an instance of a type `T`.

More generally what is the associated terminology to describe the relationship between a type `T` and a concept `C`? (I am looking for both computer engineering and theoretical computer science terms if any exist).

Comment: The meaning of T does not depend on whether a constraint has been defined for it or not. It is a one way relationship, It is not like parent and child. But I guess you could call T the domain type for C. Note I just made this up, I am not aware of a term that the community agrees on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have classes `A` and `B`, and `B` is a derived class of `A`, that is a noun property. `B` has a fundamental relationship to `A` which the very definition of `B` must explicitly claim.

Concepts don't work like that.

First and most obviously, C++ concepts don't have to involve just one type. A concept can describe the relationship *between* types. A type can be `totally_ordered`, but `indirect_strict_weak_order` requires a type that could be ordered, a comparison functor that defines the ordering, and a projection function that modifies the elements before applying the comparison functor.

Second, even single-type concepts are entirely separate from the type definition itself. It is not part of the definition of a type `A` that it satisfies some concept. That may be the *effect* of `A`'s definition, but it is not an intrinsic property of `A` the way a base class is. Instead, it is a property of what happens when you take `A` and check it against the concept.

Indeed, types can satisfy concepts accidentally. The author of the type may not have even been aware the concept *existed* when the type was written. Yet it still satisfies it.

As such, the relationship between a type and any concepts it satisfies is inherently *active*. This is not a noun property; it's a verbal property.

So a set of template arguments given to a concept are said to "satisfy" the concept if applying those arguments causes the concept to yield `true`.

However, the C++ standard library also recognizes that a concept can have requirements which cannot be enforced by code. These semantic requirements also need to be fulfilled, and there's no way for code to verify this. A set of template arguments which fulfills those semantic requirements are said to "model" the concept.

Answer (score 3):

A concept [is a predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). I'd use the term *satisfies*, as in

> A type `T` satisfies the concept `C` when...

Many concepts specify requirements on the *interface* of a type. Taking a phrase from languages with a keyword `interface`

> A type `T` implements the concept `C` when...

Comment: Thanks. Hower, this is a verb and I am looking for a noun.

Comment: @Vincent I don't think there is such a noun, maybe *instance*